# Where to store access token for frontend use

Tags: javascript, java, access-token, openid-connect, websphere-liberty

I have a liberty server with a web app and a `REST API`.

Both are secured by `openid` connect on the `Liberty server`. The api accepts access tokens for authentication. The web app is not entirely frontend so I would need liberty to handle the authentication.

I was thinking of storing the access token in a cookie and having the frontend read the cookie and add the token to any api calls. Is there a better alternative?

With the javascript readable cookie, I need to be careful with `XSS`.

Comment: Consider storing the access token in the browser local storage. When you make a request to the API, add the access token (from the storage) as a header to the request. That way there is no way of performing XSS attacks.

Comment: Isn't localstorage still readable by JS?

Comment: Access to the local storage is based on the domain from which the script is served. So everything you store in the local storage, can only be accessed from scripts that are from your domain.

Comment: Can I access local storage from the java server backend though?

Comment: No, the local storage is inside the client browser (like google chrome, mozilla)

Comment: To use local storage I would need to move authentication to the front end but I would like to keep it on the liberty side.

Comment: you could implement CSRF token to validate every request and this will prevent XSS attack.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use local storage or session storage based on your requirement. If you want to store it for that session only, you can use session storage wherein local storage is used when you want to store for long term.

Comment: this is not correct solution. read more details https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36958/is-it-safe-to-store-password-in-html5-sessionstorage